# ¿Cómo pongo un botón en un modal?

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap, modal, bootstrap-5

Los botones dentro del modal no aparecen, incluso si copio un código de una página y lo pego en mi html. Lo único que no se muestra son los botones. Aquí el código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="codigo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>CliffPedia</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <!--Barra de navegacion-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="PaginaPrincipalBootstrap.html"><img class="d-inline-block align-top" src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/91604190949969147/088A09E3C677498614C124ACE76365CBDF969000/?imw=268&imh=268&ima=fit&impolicy=Letterbox&imcolor=%23000000&letterbox=true" width="30" height="30"/>CliffPedia</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler"type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu</button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
              <a href="Yo.html" class="nav-link active">Yo</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="Contacto.html" class="nav-link active">Contacto</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="Historia.html" class="nav-link active">Historia</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Modal-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="justify-tracks: left;">
          Iniciar Sesion
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Inicio de Sesion</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="text-center">
                  <form>
                    <img src="https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/91604190949969147/088A09E3C677498614C124ACE76365CBDF969000/?imw=268&imh=268&ima=fit&impolicy=Letterbox&imcolor=%23000000&letterbox=true" height="72" alt="Logo">
                    <h1>Iniciar Sesion</h1>
                    <label for="correo" class="sr-only"></label>
                    <input type="email" id="correo" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo electronico" required autofocus>
                    <br>
                    <label for="contraseña" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" id="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="Recuerdame">Recuerdame
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <!--Modal-->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--Barra de navegacion-->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Y aquí el css:

```
.col{
    margin-left: 150px;
} 

.btn{
    position: absolute;
    left: 1710px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.container{
    background-color: rgb(160, 155, 155);
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(92, 91, 95);
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.overlay-image{
    height: 80vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;    
}
.navbar-brand{
    color: white;
}
.col{
    margin-top: 50px;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("https://cdn.planetradio.co.uk/one/media/5f6c/6239/f694/007e/c382/1df3/20151018_044604_7549_770421.jpeg?quality=80&format=jpg&width=960&ratio=16-9&crop=25,0,476,800&resize=crop");
    size: 100%;
}
```

En caso de no haberse entendido lo de arriba: Al añadir un botón con `<button>` dentro del modal no se muestra, solo se añade una especie de espacio en blanco con el que no puedes interactuar. He intentado borrando el modal que tengo ahí y copiando otro de alguna página pero es lo mismo, aún así sigue sin mostrarse el botón.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quítale la clase "btn" y funciona ;)

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

U otra opción es que a la clase "btn" que modificas en tu CSS, le cambies el nombre

```
.btn-header{
position: absolute;
left: 1710px;
background-color: grey; }
```

Y también le cambies el nombre a tu clase en el botón del "header"

```
<button type="button" class="btn-header btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" style="justify-tracks: left;">
```

Comment: Siiii muchas gracias amigo. :DDD